# Any better way for converting array to concurrent dictionary using linq or IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, extension-methods

I have an `Array` of `Person` object and I want to convert it to a `ConcurrentDictionary`. There is extension method for converting an `Array` to a `Dictionary`. Is there any extension method for converting an `Array` to a `ConcurrentDictionary`?

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name =name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, Person> PersonDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Person>(); 
Person[] PersonArray = new Person[]
{
    new Person("AAA", 30),
    new Person("BBB", 25),
    new Person("CCC",2),
    new Person("DDD", 1)
};

PersonDictionary = PersonArray.ToDictionary(person => person.Age);
```

Any similar extension method/lambda expression for converting an `Array` to a `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure, use the constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,Person>>`:

```
var personDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Person>
                       (PersonArray.ToDictionary(person => person.Age));
```

`var` infers the type to `ConcurrentDictionary<int,Person>`.

If you're going to create an extension method, as Wasp suggested, I would recommend using the following version which offers a somewhat more fluent syntax:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> 
(this IEnumerable<TValue> source, Func<TValue, TKey> valueSelector)
{
    return new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
               (source.ToDictionary(valueSelector));
}
```

The usage is similar to the `ToDictionary`, creating a consistent feel:

```
var dict = PersonArray.ToConcurrentDictionary(person => person.Age);
```

Comment: Whilst this answer is valid, [Wasp's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12396386/1149773) is superior in terms of computational and memory demands. This answer requires a `Dictionary<TKey, TElement>` to be constructed, only to be immediately discarded.

Answer (score 12):

You can write your own extension method very easily, for example like these:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
    {
        return new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>(source);
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> source, Func<TValue, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
            from v in source 
            select new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(keySelector(v), v));
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement> ToConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue, TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> source, Func<TValue, TKey> keySelector, Func<TValue, TElement> elementSelector)
    {            
        return new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement>(
            from v in source
            select new KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>(keySelector(v), elementSelector(v)));
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a good suggestion, +1. Just two minor criticisms: the parameter can be of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` and I suggest following the standard naming convention of `TKey, TValue`.

Comment: Agree, the type could be made as you said, I'll fix it. My point was more to make clear that such an extension method, if missing, is very easy to add.

Comment: oops. seems like we had similar things in mind; see my answer ;)

Comment: Yes! Help people help themselves! Everyone can build such a method himself.

Comment: I added the overload that takes a key selector + element selector. eg.`ToConcurrentDictionary(p => p.ID, p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287236) that takes `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`

```
IDictionary<int,Person> concurrentPersonDictionary = 
  new ConcurrentDictionary<int,Person>(PersonArray.ToDictionary(person => person.Age));
```